# Errors when trying to start Angular Project

Tags: angular

I am trying to start an Angular Project a fellow student created, and which works on his Computer. I keep getting a bunch of [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYPSP.png). Searching for those on the Internet didn't help, so i hope you could help me.

Comment: Do you have `moment` installed? Check in your node_modules. Or else re-install `@angular/material-moment-adapter` once gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was about 'moment' module is not present. Are you sure that moment library is installed? Check on your `package.json`. You should find a 'moment' dependency like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "moment": "^2.19.1",
  ...
}
```

I suppose you already have this dependency. You can use `npm install` to re/install all dependencies declared in the project.

If nothing happens.. try to delete node_modules and then try again `npm install`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried running "npm install" again, but "npm outdated" shows the same packages as before.

Comment: I deleted node_modules and used `npm install` again but i get the same errors as before. In my `package.json` the only 'moment' dependency is `"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.0.2"`

Comment: Try to add the moment library directly